# How to get JavaScript output via jQuery GET()?

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has a javaScript function call on it that I am hoping to be able to grab the output of this function to use on another page and when I attempt to use:

```
$.get("/test.html", function(result) {
        var value = $(result).html();
});
```

value is null. How can I call a page via ajax that would have the output of the javascript as if I had loaded that page manually?

Comment: Wait.  What?  You are trying to get the HTML of another page?  You are trying to run a function from a script in another page?

Comment: I am trying to run a function from another page that has a few document.write lines of JS in it. I need to grab the result of that function and use it in another page. Does that make sense? Its a limitation of an ad server response.

Comment: Can you post what happens when you `console.log(result)`?

Comment: Its the source of the entire page without the JS functions executed. It looks just like how you wrote it on the html page <script>functionCall(var);</script> instead of the result/output of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work.  Calling `document.write()` on a page that has already loaded will replace the entire page:

http://jsfiddle.net/JApj9/

You may be able to work something out by loading the page in a hidden iframe and reading the content of the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) and read that little section in the docs entitled "Script Execution" to understand why it should solve your problem.

```
$("#result").load("/test.html");
```

With the above line of code, the output of your `document.write` from within test.html should display inside a `<div id="result"></div>` element on the page

Comment: I had tried load initially I am getting the same result as get(). Instead of the output of the JS function I am still just getting the function call. 
    <script type="text/javascript"> showAd("1"); </script> instead of the output of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("/test.html", function(result) {
    conole.log(result); 
    var value = $(any_target).html(result);
});
```